# node-babel works very slow in Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I've setup a Docker container for developing of a node.js project. I want to use all ES6 features, so I use `babel-node` as the transpiler, but ran into a problem, that trasnpiling process takes too much time in Docker.

I am mounting app directory from my host (so I can make edits in webstorm), and I use `nodemon` to track all the changes and restart automatically the server.

```
 docker build -t lazarev/an_app .
 docker run -d -p 49160:8080 --name map -v $HOME/projects/app:/usr/src/app lazarev/an_app tail -f /dev/null
```

`nodemon -l` commang is set in a shell script, that is set in `ENTRYPOINT` in my `Dockerfile`.

**`Dockerfile`**:

```
FROM node:argon
MAINTAINER Lazarev Alexandr <lazarev@elje-group.com>

RUN mkdir /docker-entrypoint
ADD ./bootstrap.sh /docker-entrypoint

RUN locale -a

EXPOSE 8080

RUN npm install nodemon -g
RUN npm install babel-cli -g

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint/bootstrap.sh"]
```

**`bootstarp.sh`**:

```
 #!/bin/bash
echo "******INSTALL NODE MODULES******"

npm install
date
echo "******RUN THE SERVER******"
nodemon -L
date
```

**`packege.json`**:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "desc",
  "author": "Lazarev Alexandr <lazarev@elje-group.com>",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "babel-node --presets es2015 --debug server.js"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "mapnik": "^3.5.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0"
  }
}
```

It might look strange why I use `bootstrap.sh` but there are other commands that I didn't paste here.

So, my problem is that after I do some changes on my host, `nodemon` detects changes immediately, but server restart takes about half of a minute. Without compiling `ES6` via babel it is considerably faster.

Also, when I run same project on my host (my host machine is a MacbookPro with 2.5 GHz Intel Core i7 processor and 16gb ram), omitting `Docker`, everything is fast enough. So I'm convinced that the problem is in the `Docker`.

My question is: 
**Why babel-node is transpiling so slow in the Docker Container? It there s way to throttle it?**

Comment: Dors `docker stats your_container` or `docker top` show anything interesting? You can also `docker exec` and then launch `top` or anyany other command

Comment: `docker stats` command shows that cpu usage reaches 75-99% when the compiling starts, memory usage doesn't change significantly, it is about 10%.

Comment: Can you mount the node_modules directory as a volume? e.g.: ` volumes: - .node_modules_docker:/app/node_modules:delegated`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running Docker on OS X requires the use of *Docker Machine*. From the [Docker OS X docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/mac/):

> Because the Docker daemon uses Linux-specific kernel features, you
>   can’t run Docker natively in OS X. Instead, you must use
>   docker-machine to create and attach to a virtual machine (VM). This
>   machine is a Linux VM that hosts Docker for you on your Mac.

Mounting files through a VM, and then subsequently into your running container is **slow**. Making files available from your host is generally ok, but wanting those files to be watched, compiled and synced is not.

I hit this same problem on Windows when running through *boot2Docker* several years ago, and ultimately there isn't much you can do about it. (There are numerous posts on this available through simple searches, eg https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/593)

My solution was to switch to Ubuntu. The performance of shared volumes on non-linux machines is unlikely to change very soon.

You might want to have a look at the [docker-osx-dev](https://github.com/brikis98/docker-osx-dev) project which uses *rsync* and claims *"mounted folders is on par with native OS X performance and standard file watching mechanisms work properly"*.

Comment: I find this strange.  I'm using docker on a VM, it's not the same docker app but virtualization isn't giving me problems.  Though, a difference for me is that I'm going straight through virtualbox and not using boot2Docker and I'm not using shared volumes. I've seen people use nfs and get much better performance out of shared volumes.

Comment: How do you get files from your host (outside VM) to your container (inside VM) without using a shared volume?

Comment: I do all of my development in vim.  Anything I need in the box comes through a git ref or I wget it.  I haven't had instances yet where I need some file that is not downloadable through command line somehow. I suppose, if that came up, I would add a shared folder, but it wouldn't be a working directory for me.

Comment: Right, so you essentially avoid the problem. You're files exist on the same 'machine' as the container, so its (almost) as though they are being mounted as they would be on a regular linux/docker setup. This is pretty much the only solution for OP, but it doesn't sound like it's what they want. (And is why I ended up completely changing my OS after 15 years dev on Windows!)

Comment: Thanks, but switching os is not an option for me. I am looking towards nfs.

Comment: Understand changing OS isn't a small thing, it wasn't for me either. But I spent so long trying to improve things with NFS and rsync and it didn't make enough difference. Most non-linux teams tend to choose simply not to be developing inside the container and simply test/run it occasionally in CI.

Comment: You said you've run into that problem several years ago, maybe things have changed :)

Comment: See my addition to original answer above. Good luck!